# Open image downloaded with Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent

When I download an image with Google Chrome I hit the Open button in the Snackbar, now I have a list of apps that can open the image and one of them is my app.

When I receive an Intent, I use this code to get the path of the image to open:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
String type = intent.getType();
```

and

```
intent.getData().toString()
```

to get the path of the image.

It works fine, but with chrome I don't get the real path but something like

```
://downloads/my_downloads/532
```

where the real path is

```
/storage/emulated/0/Downloads/5_6.jpg
```

How do I get the real path from the Intent received from Chrome?
Where dows chrome save the image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve this problem ordering all the images in the Download folder by date and showing the most recent image.

Answer (score 2):

Try out this one :

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

Comment: But how do I know which is the file I downloaded? Because in that folder I have all the images.

Comment: Sorry maybe I misunderstood your question. What the original problem? Getting the bitmap?

Comment: I want to get the exact path of the image I just downloaded, with your answer I have the path of the image's folder.

Comment: Yes, sure, but why for do you need this path, you can work with the Uri - it's really flexible : ImageView.setImageUri(), ContentResolver.openInputStream(), MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver() , Uri.parse(getIntent().getDataString()))

Comment: I'm sorry but I need the path. Do you know how can I convert this Uri to a String path?